# Why is ampersand followed by asterisk "&*" used here?

Tags: rust

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html#examples

```rs
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Condvar};
use std::thread;

let pair = Arc::new((Mutex::new(false), Condvar::new()));
let pair2 = Arc::clone(&pair);

// Inside of our lock, spawn a new thread, and then wait for it to start.
thread::spawn(move|| {
    let (lock, cvar) = &*pair2;
    let mut started = lock.lock().unwrap();
    *started = true;
    // We notify the condvar that the value has changed.
    cvar.notify_one();
});

// Wait for the thread to start up.
let (lock, cvar) = &*pair;
let mut started = lock.lock().unwrap();
while !*started {
    started = cvar.wait(started).unwrap();
}
```

Why isn't 17th line written like this:

```rs
let (lock, cvar) = pair;
```

Or like this:

```rs
let (lock, cvar) = *pair;
```

Or somehow else

Comment: What happens if you try?

Answer (score 4):

The asterisk makes `Arc<(Mutex<bool>, Condvar)>` become `(Mutex<bool>, Condvar)`. Then the ampersand makes it become a `&(Mutex<bool>, Condvar)`.

So as a result, `lock`'s type is `&Mutex<bool>` and `cvar`'s type is `&Condvar`.

Now, let's see why we need the `&` by trying to remove it:

```
let (lock, cvar) = *pair;
```

The compiler explains the problem:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of an `Arc`
  --> src/main.rs:26:24
   |
26 |     let (lock, cvar) = *pair;
   |          ----  ----    ^^^^^ help: consider borrowing here: `&*pair`
   |          |     |
   |          |     ...and here
   |          data moved here
   |
   = note: move occurs because these variables have types that don't implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: Why did they take a reference to it, not moved it?

Comment: If it were moved into the thread, it wouldn't be usable at the "Wait for the thread to start up." anymore.

Comment: ooh, got it ! tysm

Comment: It's basically just a shortcut for calling `pair.deref()`.